# Monsgoosastic es_indexed not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoosastic

I have a model schema a part of which I want to index in ElasticSearch. According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic), setting:

```
es_indexed: true
```

Along with the desired schema field will only index that key on operations related to ElasticSearch. I have a large schema of around 20 fields of which only 5 need to be indexed.

Problem is, these flags are being ignored and the entire document is being indexed.

```
var PersonSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, es_indexed: true},
    address: address: {
        street_address: {type: String},
        locality: {type: String},
        region: {type: String},
        zip: {type: String},
        landmark: {type: String},
        neighbourhood : {type: [String]}
    },
    ...
    tags: {type:[String], index:true, es_indexed: true},
    ...
})

PersonSchema.plugin(mongoosastic);

var Person = Mongoose.model("Merchant", PersonSchema);
```

After I call

```
var stream = Merchant.synchronize()
        , count = 0;

    stream.on('data', function(err, doc){
        count++;
        console.log('indexing: '+ count+ ' done');
    });
    stream.on('close', function(){
        console.log('indexed ' + count + ' documents!');
    });

    stream.on('error', function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
```

The entire document is saved, including address and other unnecessary fields. Why are the `es_indexed: true` flags not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you have to provide an es_indexed property for all fields, to explicitly say whether you want to include the field or not.

```
var PersonSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, es_indexed: true},
    address: address: {
        es_indexed: false,             //Exclusion needs to be specified as well
        street_address: {type: String},
        locality: {type: String},
        region: {type: String},
        zip: {type: String},
        landmark: {type: String},
        neighbourhood : {type: [String]}
    },
    ...
    tags: {type:[String], index:true, es_indexed: true},
    ...
})
```

Comment: Encountered this issue myself and dug into it a little and found this change to the project. https://github.com/taterbase/mongoosastic/pull/74

Sub-objects aren't ever added to the "implicitFields" array now as they do not have a type, so they are not removed in the final step where it checks if es_indexed is set on another field. The comments in the change seem to indicate this was a known defect introduced so I don't know if there will have be a better solution than the one you provided here.